# Does "pure git" have the concept of a pull request?

Tags: git, version-control, git-pull, pull-request

Of course, there's `git pull`, but is there a formalized method (i.e. not an ad hoc method such as sending an email) of making a pull request in "pure" git?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The answer is yes.

The `pull request` is based upon git internal feature name : `request-pull`

#### `git request-pull`

Here are the doc for this feature

- https://git-scm.com/docs/git-request-pull
- https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-request-pull.html

Based upon this concept the `pull request` was created and you can imagine were the name came from....

---

### ***`Other similar methods:`***

#### `git format-patch`

```
git format-patch master --stdout > XXXX.patch
```

> ***`git format-patch`***
>
> This command will create patch which can later on can be applied on top of any other commit using the `git apply` command
>
> Prepare each commit with its patch in one file per commit, formatted to resemble UNIX mailbox format. The output of this command is convenient for e-mail submission or for use with git am.
>
> ***`git apply`***
>
> Reads the supplied diff output (i.e. "a patch") and applies it to files. With the `--index` option the patch is also applied to the index, and with the `--cached` option the patch is only applied to the index.
>
> Without these options, the command applies the patch only to files, and does not require them to be in a Git repository.

Comment: But to be clear, `git request-pull` outputs some text that you can then send in an email, or something. It doesn't send anything to anyone, or interact with the remote git repo in any way. A "plain" git repo or "plain" git server doesn't have such an *object* as a "pull request". In vanilla git, a pull-request exists in the minds of the people that are dealing with it. In GitHub, and other software, it's codified.

Comment: I totaly agree, The pull request is something that was "invented" by GitHub  somewher around 2010 or so